# Is it possible to summarise standardized mean differences deriving from different variables in a meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, standardized-mean-difference

I am conducting a meta-analysis on the alteration of fine roots in forest soil as a consequence of soil compaction after logging operations. I have already the database which is made up of studies which compared fine roots in the compacted soil (treatment) with not compacted one (control). I would like to use Hedges' g as measure of the effect size. The problem is that the various studies reported fine roots in the soil sometimes as biomass per surface unit sometimes as number per surface unit. I am wondering if it is possible to consider all these studies in a unique database, considering that the standardized mean difference which I want to use as effect size measure has not a measure unit. To summarise the question is if I can have only one database and use g to calculate the effect size for all the studies ot if I have to separate into two databases data measuring fine roots biomass and data measuring fine roots number.

Comment: To some extent this relies on detailed knowledge of the underlying science but your two measures do not look too different to me so it might be OK. I think it would be mandatory to include a moderator to distinguish the two measurements. Of course that would mean you do not have an overall effect size but that may not matter. If you want to include other moderators I would also interact them with measure type.

Comment: Yes it was properly what I was thinking, Thank you for your valuable suggestion